# Why won't my android app increase time when it loops through?

Tags: java, android

I'm working on making an app for myself that will help me do sprints outside. The idea is that a sound will play after two minutes to signify the time to sprint. After one minute of sprinting it will play another sound to signify the time to walk. And repeat. For some reason I can't get the time to be increased each time it goes through the loop. It's currently set to 10 and 15 seconds due to ease of trial and error. Thank you for any help! Here's the code:

```
package com.example.sprinttrial;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.media.Ringtone;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Chronometer;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Chronometer chronometer;
    private long pauseOffset;
    private boolean running;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {
            this.getSupportActionBar().hide();
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e){}
        
        chronometer = findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
        chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

        chronometer.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
                System.out.println(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase());
                int walkTimeVariable = 10000;
                int walkTimeVariableDiff = 10999;
                int runTimeVariable = 15000;
                int runTimeVariableDiff = 15999;
                boolean walkedPlayed = false;
                boolean runPlayed = false;
                if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase() >= walkTimeVariable && SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase() < walkTimeVariableDiff && walkedPlayed == false) {
                    walkedPlayed = true;
                    Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                    Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
                    r.play();

                    System.out.println("Working");
                } else if ((SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase()) >= runTimeVariable && SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase() < runTimeVariableDiff && runPlayed == false) {
                    System.out.println("Working As Well");
                    runPlayed = true;
                    long ringDelay = 500;
                    Uri notification = RingtoneManager
                            .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
                    final Ringtone alarmRingtone = RingtoneManager
                            .getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
                    alarmRingtone.play();
                    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            alarmRingtone.stop();
                        }
                    };
                    Timer timer = new Timer();
                    timer.schedule(task, ringDelay);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Please work");
                    if(walkedPlayed){
                        System.out.println("WORK MAN");
                        walkTimeVariable += 10000;
                        walkTimeVariableDiff += 10000;
                        walkedPlayed = false;
                    }
                    if(runPlayed) {
                        System.out.println("WORK OMG");
                        runTimeVariable += 10000;
                        runTimeVariableDiff += 10000;
                        runPlayed = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }




    public void startChronometer(View v) {
        System.out.println("SIGH");
        if (!running){
            chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - pauseOffset);
            chronometer.start();
            running = true;
        }
    }

    public void pauseChronometer(View v) {
        if (running){
            chronometer.stop();
            pauseOffset = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase();
            running = false;
        }

    }

    public void resetChronometer(View v) {
        chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        pauseOffset = 0;
    }
}
```